# Looking for recommendations on how to approch a face verification system and trying to find pre-trained models

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision

I have failed miserably trying to train a face verification network on my own hardware. Here by face verification i mean looking at two photos and telling its the same person or not. So any recommendations for pre trained models?

there are many articles on implementation of face-net for face identification but none for face verification. Can anyone guide me if you know of any pre trained models that i can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you will need a [FaceNet](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.03832) pretrained model. A FaceNet model creates an embedding vector for a human face in an image. As mentioned in the paper, researchers have used clustering algorithms using the embedded face vectors. Hence, you get a 128 or 256-dimensional vector which represents that human face.

- After you've generated an embedding vector from the images of the two subjects, you can find the [cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) of both the vectors, which is a common metric used for vectors comparison.
- By some experimenting, you can find some **threshold similarity score**, meaning, if the similarity scores exceed this threshold score, the faces are of the same subjects.

You can discover some references here:

1. https://medium.com/@vinayakvarrier/building-a-real-time-face-recognition-system-using-pre-trained-facenet-model-f1a277a06947
2. https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-a-face-recognition-system-using-facenet-in-keras-and-an-svm-classifier/